# i want to display session expired message when i refresh my login page after logout

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have created login and logout pages. When I click on logout button, logout page will be displayed but when I refresh the login page again welcome page again displayed.

So, I want to show the message like session has been expired login again.
 I don't know the exact code please can anyone answer my question
I am using *Spring MVC* and *Hibernate*.

Comment: on refresh the request goes to current `welcome` page and there you have to check it again for logged in user if session expired then redirect to `login` page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `spring security` for managing authentication and authorization of pages in your application. [This](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-xml-example/) example should help you.

If you want to manage sessions on your own..

- Set some session parameter (userID?) when the user is logged in and redirect to welcome page (and check if the parameter is set)
- Set the same parameter null

Example:

Login:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome")
public String login(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session == null || session.getAttribute("userid") == null){
        session.setAttribute("expired") = "Session expired!"; // display this message in your page
        return "index";// session expired redirect to login or custom page
    }
    return "welcome";
}
```

Logout:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout")
public String logout(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    session.setAttribute("userid") = null;
    return "index";
}
```

HTH

Comment: i used this code there is no errors but after logout when i was going back to the welcome page and click on any function it was opening thats the problem again what i have to do?

Comment: once you logout.. you shouldnt be able to reload welcome page.. (above code does that).. But it wont work when you hit `back` button for navigating to that page.. `spring-security` is the only choice (AFAIK) for restricting access to a page through `back-button`.

Comment: @Lokeshkumar .. If this answer solved your problem.. accept it.. so that it will help others.. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)